# Save File on Filesystem using werkzeug

Tags: python, python-2.7, wsgi, werkzeug

I am trying to save uploaded file on my system. at specific path but i am getting this error in windows. can someone tell me where i am doing mistake?

system: windows 8.1
python version: 2.7

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
from werkzeug.wrappers import BaseRequest, BaseResponse
import os

def view_file(req):
    if not 'file' in req.files:
        return BaseResponse('no file uploaded')
    f = req.files['file']

    s = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test"
    f.save(s, f.filename)
    return BaseResponse('File Saved!')


def upload_file(req):
    return BaseResponse('''
    <h1>Upload File</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
    ''', mimetype='text/html')


def application(environ, start_response):
    req = BaseRequest(environ)
    if req.method == 'POST':
        resp = view_file(req)
    else:
        resp = upload_file(req)
    return resp(environ, start_response)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_simple('localhost', 5000, application, use_debugger=True)
```

**here is traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test.py", line 30, in application
    resp = view_file(req)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test.py", line 13, in view_file
    f.save(s, f.filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\datastructures.py", line 2703, in
 save
    dst = open(dst, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'C:\\Users\x07dmin\\Desktop
\test'
```

Comment: You need to escape ```\``` in your path to the file.

Comment: after changing   s = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test"  now getting IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test'

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why are you all mixing up all things, just keep it easy and clean.
Make two files called 'app.py' and 'index.html' and make a folder in your app root dirrectory called "upload"

index.html

```
<h1>Upload File</h1>
<form action="/uploader" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request,render_template
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

uploads_dir = "upload"

@app.route("/") 
def index(): 
        return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def uploader():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        input = request.files['file']
        input.save(os.path.join(uploads_dir, secure_filename(input.filename)))
        #print(input)
        return "<h2>Successfully uploaded</h2>"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

You can also redirect to other page after saving the file:

```
return render_template(otherpage.html)
```

Comment: I'm getting an internal server error (500) when I send the POST request on postman. The script crashes with the error ``` FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './static/2.pdf' ``` static is my upload folder and 2.pdf is the file I want to upload and save in the static folder

Comment: I'm working with werkzeug 1.0.1 and with this I need `from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `\a` is being interpreted as [a control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character).

You should write the path like this:

```
s = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test"
```

If you're calling `.save()` you must also close the file: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage.save

Also you need to provide a buffer size to `.save()`.

So try:

```
f.save(s, buffer_size=16384)
f.close()
```

Comment: now getting IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test'

Comment: Make sure the user running the script has the same permissions as the permissions of the admin directory.

Comment: yes i am running the script as admin.. and folder have all access rights.

Comment: till getting IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\test'

Comment: The shell by default does not run in administrative mode. Are you sure you're running it in administrative mode?

Comment: yes i have run it as admin and also give the permission to folder. the same code working fine in linux.

Comment: @ADVALAKI: please see additional edit. I believe you are calling `.save()` incorrectly.